# Перевести "чистый" JavaScript в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой код

```
var parent = document.getElementById('main');
var firstKid = parent.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
```

Как написать такой код на jQuery?

Comment: Вариант покороче: `var firstKid = $("#main div:first");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос... зачем?
Если по сути то:

```
var parent = $('#main');
var firstKid = parent.find('div').eq(0);
```